# object and array confusion using for foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is says i is undefined in line  `url: data.url[i]`??

```
  $scope.data = [{
    "url":"http://www.google.com"
  },
  {
        "url":"http://www.bing.com"
  },{
        "url":"http://www.yahoo.com"
  }];

            angular.forEach($scope.data, function(data){
                //var links = data.url;
  console.log(data);
  //I need array to be use in
                chrome.tabs.create({
                    url: data.url[i]
                });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `i` at all.  `data` already refers to the individual item.

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(data){
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: data.url
    });
});
```

Although to avoid confusion, you might want to use a parameter name other than `data` in the `forEach` function, since your $scope variable is also named `data`.

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item){
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: item.url
    });
});
```

Comment: I see thanks! I read it wrongly.. It worked but you u know how to focus on the first link? so far I focus on yahoo coz it is the last link, I want window focus on google.com which is the firstly opened tab. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about how you're creating tabs.